# powershell search multiple domains for computer

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need some help. I wrote a PowerShell script that grabs a text file as an input with a list of computer names. It then checks the Active Directory for the machine name. If the machine is found it writes it to one text file, and if the machine is not found, it writes it to a separate file. The idea being I get two lists... A "good" and a "bad" list. the problem is that it only queries the domain I am in and I need it to query all the domains in a forest and am stuck. can someone lend a hand? Here is my code as it stands:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$AdminCredentials = Get-Credential "Domain\AdminAccount"

$objForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()

$domains = @($objForest.Domains | Select-Object Name)

$computers = gc -Path "C:\MachinesInDifferentAds.txt"

$computer_count = $Computers.Length;
$i = 0;
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
   Try
   {
   (Get-ADComputer $computer -Credential $AdminCredentials | FT Name)
        $computer | out-file -append -filepath "C:\ComputersInAd.txt"
   }
   Catch
   {
        $computer | out-file -append -filepath "C:\ComputersNotInAd.txt"
   }
$computer_progress = [int][Math]::Ceiling((($i / $computer_count) * 100))
Write-Progress  "Querying the AD" -PercentComplete $computer_progress -Status "Percent Complete - $computer_progress%" -Id 1;
Sleep(1);
$i++;
}
```

Comment: You have your list of domains, just loop through them and use the `-Server` switch on `Get-Adcomputer` to check each of them for each computer.

Comment: Or depending on the number of entries in the list, retrieve *all* machine names from all domains up front and correlate with the input list

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought about that, but theoretically this list could contain upwards of 2,000 machines in 20 different domains. Sorry... I should have mentioned that in my original posting

Comment: @MikeGaruccio I tried that. The problem is that I get a list showing that computer a computer wasn't found 19 times, and then in another list see it was found once.

Comment: use a boolean, set it to `false` at the start of checking each computer and only flip it to `true` if the computer gets found in one of the domains, then a simple `if` after checking each domain to write to one file if `true` and the other if `false`, then flip the boolean back to `false` before checking the next computer